# How to get user email from google plus oauth

Tags: google-plus

Link: https://sites.google.com/site/oauthgoog/Home/emaildisplayscope

From the link above I add the email scope

```
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.me
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email
```

But I dont understand the following

*Once you have a valid OAuth token, you can use it to make API calls to the Email Display API endpoint:
https://www.googleapis.com/userinfo/email
If the token is not valid, a 401 error will be returned.  If the token is valid, then the user's Email address will be returned.  The API will also return a boolean value to indicate whether Google has verified that the user owns that Email address.  However most installed applications will ignore that value.*

How to make a call to the Email Display API endpoint? Using https://www.googleapis.com/userinfo/email

Answer (score 54, accepted):

Set your scopes to:

- https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email and
- https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile

And use the endpoint:

https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/userinfo?alt=json

Usage:

```
get https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/userinfo?alt=json&access_token=youraccess_token
```

You will get JSON:

```
{ "id": "xx", 
  "name": "xx", 
  "given_name": "xx", 
  "family_name": "xx", 
  "link": "xx", 
  "picture": "xx", 
  "gender": "xx", 
  "locale": "xx" 
}
```

Comment: It returns { "data": { "email": "xxx@gmail.com", "isVerified": true } } And i cant get the email only..

Comment: if your using JQuery try jQuery.parseJSON( <json string from above> ).email

Comment: When I try this, I'm getting only user id (:(

Comment: Links are expired. paste new documentation links

Comment: If you mean the https://www.googleapis.com/auth/XXX links - those are not documentation. They are the scopes and enpoint that needs to be set to your GoogleOAuthParameters object. (e.g. oauthParameters.setScope(<scope URL>); )

Comment: you will get only the email if you only ask for the email in the scopes, depending on the scope you have you can also get the circles, friends, name, etc

Comment: Can I get all the emails from the login user account.

Answer (score 34):

The scopes have changed for Google+ Sign-In.

Set your scopes to:

```
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.login
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email
```

The JavaScript calls look like this:

```
gapi.client.load('oauth2', 'v2', function() {
  gapi.client.oauth2.userinfo.get().execute(function(resp) {
    // Shows user email
    console.log(resp.email);
  })
});

gapi.client.load('plus', 'v1', function() {
  gapi.client.plus.people.get( {'userId' : 'me'} ).execute(function(resp) {
    // Shows profile information
    console.log(resp);
  })
});
```

More information https://developers.google.com/+.

Edit: Note that you do not need scopes for plus.me or userinfo.profile.

Comment: Scopes should be space delimited.

Answer (score 17):

Now we use GoogleAPI with Google+

As on December 2013, here is the most updated website;

https://developers.google.com/+/

Then for SignIn for Web

https://developers.google.com/+/web/signin/

Choosing a sign-in flow

->Client-side flow

->**Initiate the sign-in flow with JavaScript** (*I believe this is the latest technology*)

https://developers.google.com/+/web/signin/javascript-flow

> Initiating the Google+ Sign-In flow with JavaScript
>
> You can start the Google+ Sign-In flow by using the **gapi.auth.signIn()**
>   method. This method gives you a lot of flexibility to decide how and
>   when to prompt the user to authorize your app and sign-in.

https://developers.google.com/+/web/api/javascript#gapiauthsigninparameters

> **gapi.auth.signIn(parameters)**
>
> Initiates the client-side Google+ Sign-In OAuth 2.0 flow. Similar to
>   gapi.auth.authorize() except that this method supports the advanced
>   Google+ Sign-In features, including over-the-air installs of Android
>   apps. This method is a JavaScript alternative to using the Google+
>   Sign-In button widget.

https://developers.google.com/+/web/signin/javascript-flow

- **Try it** Page  to trigger the sign-in flow with **gapi.auth.signIn()**

https://google-developers.appspot.com/+/demos/signin_demo_render (SourceCode)

You will try this and for your own, follow

Step 1: Create a client ID and client secret

Ignore the following step,

Actually, you need clientID only and replace the one in the source code of **Try it** above.

Add scope  https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email

```
var options = {
  'callback': loginFinished,
  'approvalprompt': 'force',
  'clientid': 'YOURID.apps.googleusercontent.com',
  'scope': 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.login https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email',
  'requestvisibleactions': 'http://schemas.google.com/CommentActivity http://schemas.google.com/ReviewActivity',
  'cookiepolicy': 'single_host_origin'
};
```

Add

```
gapi.client.load('oauth2', 'v2', function()
  {
    gapi.client.oauth2.userinfo.get()
      .execute(function(resp)
      {
        // Shows user email
        console.log(resp.email);
      });
  });
```

Here is the full working and concise code based on the above:

```
<html>
<head>
  <title>Google+ Sign-in button demo: rendering with JavaScript</title>
  <style type="text/css">
  html, body { margin: 0; padding:0;}
  #signin-button {
   padding: 5px;
  }
  #oauth2-results pre { margin: 0; padding:0; width: 600px;}
  .hide { display: none;}
  .show { display: block;}
  </style>

  <script src="https://apis.google.com/js/client:platform.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
var loginFinished = function(authResult)
{
  if (authResult)
  {
    console.log(authResult);
  }

  gapi.client.load('oauth2', 'v2', function()
  {
    gapi.client.oauth2.userinfo.get()
      .execute(function(resp)
      {
        // Shows user email
        console.log(resp.email);
      });
  });

};

var options = {
  'callback': loginFinished,
  'approvalprompt': 'force',
  'clientid': 'YOURID.apps.googleusercontent.com',
  'scope': 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.login https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email',
  'requestvisibleactions': 'http://schemas.google.com/CommentActivity http://schemas.google.com/ReviewActivity',
  'cookiepolicy': 'single_host_origin'
};

var renderBtn = function()
{
  gapi.signin.render('renderMe', options);
}
  </script>

</head>
<body onload ="renderBtn()">
   <div id="renderMe"></div>  
</body>
</html>
```

### No HTML output, but console. so open browser's Developers Console tools to view the result.

Answer (score 1):

I did this in angularjs, in the Ionic framework, and it works., try this.

```
controller("OauthExample", function($scope, $cordovaOauth, $http) {

    $scope.googleLogin = function() {
        $cordovaOauth.google("YOUR CLIENTID", ["https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email", "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile"]).then(function(result) {
            window.localStorage.setItem("access_token", result.access_token);
            $scope.token=JSON.stringify(result);

        }, function(error) {
            console.log(error);
        });
    }


        $scope.getProfileInfo = function() {
            console.log(window.localStorage.getItem('access_token'));
        $http.defaults.headers.common.Authorization = "Bearer " + window.localStorage.getItem("access_token");
        $http.get("https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/userinfo?alt=json")
            .success(function(data) {
                console.log(data);
                console.log(data.email);
            })
            .error(function(error) {
                console.log(error);
            });
    }

});
```