# How to download google drive file using OAuth 2.0 client ID?

Tags: google-drive-api

I've been trying for quite a while to download a settings file from a user's google drive for a web app of mine.  I'm able to successfully upload a file using javascript, but now I cannot get the [google example download](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files/get) code to work to obtain back the contents of the file.  Here's the current code. I'm able to obtain the file's metadata.

```
   function downloadFile(file) {
    if (file.downloadUrl) {
        var accessToken = gapi.auth.getToken().access_token; <-Error
        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.open('GET', file.downloadUrl);
        xhr.setRequestHeader('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + accessToken);
        xhr.onload = function() {
            console.log(xhr.responseText);
        };
        xhr.onerror = function() {
            console.log("ERROR");
        };
        xhr.send();
    } else {
        console.log("No file.downloadUrl");
    }
}
```

The console error says "Cannot read property 'access_token' of null" which  I think it may be because it requires an API key but I'm using a client id to sign people in. Is there a way to do this without using the API key and with the client id?

Comment: possible duplicate - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23654749/google-app-engine-authorization-returning-null. Your request is not being process since `getToken` is null (which indicates that the application is not authorized properly)

Answer (score 0):

You need to have an API key to work with any of Google's APIs.
https://developers.google.com/loader/signup

Is there any specific reason why you don't want to sign up for one?

Comment: I mean I don't know much about this, but I am already interacting with the google api.  I can upload a file into a user's Drive using my client ID. I didn't think I needed both an API key and a client id.  I also wasn't sure how to integrate both into my webapp

Comment: That was my mistake, you shouldn't need an API key for Drive. The specific error is more than likely because of an authentication error. I'm assuming you're authenticating before this?

Comment: You may also want to look at exporting the file. https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/reference/files/export

Comment: Yes I'm using a sign in button from their examples https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/build-button  And that looks like it's for google docs. I'm trying to just upload a simple txt file using V2.