# How to get email from social network (Identity framework)

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-identity

**What I have**: ASP.NET WebAPI application with Identity framework.

**What I want**: use twitter and facebook for registration and auth.

**What is the problem**: Identity framework doesn't request for email and other personal information. It returns only username.

Thanks.

Comment: **What you didn't read**: [FAQ], [ask]

Comment: Note that twitter does not provide email address via OAuth. Facebook and Google do, but not twitter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Identity uses OAuth.

Twitter:

> The API won't return an email address to you. If you're interested in a user's email address, you'll have to ask the user for it within your own application as a completely distinct act.

Google+:

> [How to get user email from google plus oauth](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11606101/how-to-get-user-email-from-google-plus-oauth)

Facebook:

> [Get ExtraData from MVC5 framework OAuth/OWin identity provider with external auth provider](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17937553/get-extradata-from-mvc5-framework-oauth-owin-identity-provider-with-external-aut)

Answer (score 1):

In the Startup.Auth.cs file before this code block,

```
app.UseFacebookAuthentication(facebookAuthenticationOptions);
```

you should add

```
facebookAuthenticationOptions.Scope.Add("email");
```

Comment: Then to get the email, check the email claim from the claims cookie after authentication.

Comment: Take note however that even adding that scope, if the targeted user doesn't share his/her email (FB settings) then the framework won't be able to get it