# Google+ API Javascript get Birthday

Tags: javascript, google-api, google-plus, google-api-js-client

I was successful in retrieving user's basic profile, but I want to fetch birthday as well. How can I make this to work? Check my codes:

```
<script src="https://apis.google.com/js/platform.js" async defer></script>
<meta name="google-signin-client_id" content="XXXXXXXXXXXXXX">

<script>
function onSignIn(googleUser) {
var profile = googleUser.getBasicProfile();
console.log('ID: ' + profile.getId()); 
console.log('Name: ' + profile.getName());
console.log('Image URL: ' + profile.getImageUrl());
console.log('Email: ' + profile.getEmail());

});                                                          

}
</script>


<div class="g-signin2" data-onsuccess="onSignIn"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

BasicProfile doesn't contain birthday. You have to [manually retrieve profile information using Google+ API](https://developers.google.com/+/web/people/#retrieve_profile_information). Here is working code that does that: https://stackoverflow.com/a/29903252/1256609