# Fetching Google Plus profile url and email

Tags: api, google-api, google-plus, google-contacts-api, google-signin

If I open someone's Google Plus Profile Page I see contact info and information shared on Google Plus. I looking for similar information on Google API. I'm trying to fetch list of user's contacts with email and google plus profile id, that's all.

Here I can fetch user connections with Google Plus profile url but without email or phone number.

`https://people.googleapis.com/v1/people/me/connections`

Here I can fetch person contacts with email and phone number (OAuth2) - without Google Plus profile url nor id

`https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/contacts/{GOOGLE_ACCOUNT_NAME}%40gmail.com/full?alt=json`

But I don't know how to combine this two outputs, to get have Google Plus profile url and contact information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct. To retrieve profile information for a user, use the [`people.get API method`](https://developers.google.com/+/web/api/rest/latest/people/get). To get profile information for the currently authorized user, use the `userId` value of `me`.

```
gapi.client.load('plus','v1', function(){
var request = gapi.client.plus.people.get({
'userId': 'me'
});
request.execute(function(resp) {
console.log('Retrieved profile for:' + resp.displayName);
});
});
```

Note that this method requires authentication using a token that has been granted the [OAuth scope](https://developers.google.com/+/web/api/rest/oauth) `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.login or https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.me`.

```
Plus.People.List listPeople = plus.people().list(
"me", "visible");
listPeople.setMaxResults(5L);

PeopleFeed peopleFeed = listPeople.execute();
List<Person> people = peopleFeed.getItems();

// Loop through until we arrive at an empty page
while (people != null) {
for (Person person : people) {
System.out.println(person.getDisplayName());
}

// We will know we are on the last page when the next page token is
// null.
// If this is the case, break.
if (peopleFeed.getNextPageToken() == null) {
break;
}

// Prepare the next page of results
listPeople.setPageToken(peopleFeed.getNextPageToken());

// Execute and process the next page request
peopleFeed = listPeople.execute();
people = peopleFeed.getItems();
}
```

Here's a related SO ticket which discuss how to fetch user email from Google+ Oauth: [How to get user email from google plus oauth](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11606101/how-to-get-user-email-from-google-plus-oauth)

Comment: I want my friends emails, not just authorized user.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [Google Api](https://developers.google.com/+/web/api/rest/latest/people/get) to fetch the user profile. For this

1. Create project in [google api console](https://console.developers.google.com).Configure the credentials client id,client secret. Add your redirect uri.
2. Authorize the user with OAuth2.0 from your project with scopes  **https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.me , https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.login**.
3. Retrieve the response code after authorization.Give POST method to the token endpoint [url](https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v4/token).
4. Retrieve the access_token, refresh_token,id_token etc from gooogle plus.
5. By using the access_token. call GET method to the url "https://www.googleapis.com/plus/v1/people/me/?access_token='{YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN}'".

You will be given by an json array containing the authorized user profile details like email, name, id etc.

Comment: I want my friends emails, not just authorized user.