# G Suit - Token Validation like unprotect

Tags: google-oauth, access-token, google-admin-sdk, google-workspace

I have an G-Suite Account..I have created a project in developer console. In that i have chosen the Oauth client Id credential for Application Type (Others). I have received client secret and Client ID..... Using this i have tried the sample mvc https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/quickstart/dotnet I have received the token with Below information

1.access_token
2.Experiences
3.refresh_token
4.Token_Type and so on…

I cant find any user related information (eg: UserId) in the token for Authenticate in our application (used tokeninfo api to validate token). I get below response

```
{
    "issued_to": "123456789234.apps.googleusercontent.com",
    "audience": "123456789234.apps.googleusercontent.com",
    "scope": "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/admin.directory.user https://www.googleapis.com/auth/admin.directory.user.readonly",
    "expires_in": 3520,
    "access_type": "online"
}
```

How to get userid in access_token?

Answer (score 0):

If you are try to get their user information you have to add [**`https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile`**](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/googlescopes#oauth2v2) in your scopes.

> View your basic profile info

---

Here is some additional reference:

- [How to get user email from google plus oauth](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11606209/5995040)
- [How to identify a Google OAuth2 user?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8713360/5995040)

Hope this helps.